# wcf strange behaviors

Tags: c#, wcf, formatting

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Coevery.Services.Document.DocumentService" 
             behaviorConfiguration="aaa">
      <endpoint address="" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="documentbinding" 
                contract="Coevery.Services.Document.IDocumentService">
      </endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
               allowCookies="true">
        <security mode="None">
        </security>
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                      maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                      maxDepth="2147483647" 
                      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
      </binding>
      <binding name="documentbinding" 
               closeTimeout="04:01:00" 
               openTimeout="04:01:00" 
               receiveTimeout="04:10:00" 
               sendTimeout="04:01:00" 
               allowCookies="false" 
               bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
               hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
               maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
               maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
               messageEncoding="Mtom" 
               textEncoding="utf-8" 
               useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                      maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="aaa">
        <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" 
                              serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure"
                              messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure" 
                              suppressAuditFailure="true" />
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <serviceCertificate findValue="WCfServer" 
                              storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                              storeName="TrustedPeople"
                              x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="True" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

If behavior name="aaa" => Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.
but without a name then it's ok.

Does anyone know what's wrong with that ? i get lost when using wcf every time :D

Comment: Try this:  Leave the name (aaa) for the behavior, and add a mex endpoint and see if it works then.  @voo is correct below about default behaviors, but since your referencing the behavior in the service tag, I'm not 100% sure it's a WCF defaults issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is the feature of WCF 4. When you ommit the name, WCF service considers it a a default behaviour. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx:

> In WCF 3.x, you have to define named behavior configurations that you
>   explicitly apply to services and endpoints through the
>   “behaviorConfiguration” attribute. With WCF 4, you can define default
>   behavior configurations by omitting the name in the configuration
>   definition. If you add these default behaviors to machine.config,
>   they’ll apply to all services or endpoints hosted on the machine.

Comment: However, in the config file above the service specifically references the named service behavior.  So it shouldn't be a default behavior issue.  I wonder if it would work if OP kept the name and added a mex endpoint?